# Pandas Dataframe.rolling.apply() can only deal with single column, how to rolling for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on financial problems, which asks me to generate a rolling window for several variables. But Dataframe.rolling.apply() can only deal with single column. I want to do something for all the columns in the dataframe, in a period. How can I realize that? For example:

```
       windcode       date     volume  ...  adjlow  adjclose   open
0     600973.SH 2015-12-25   78848.45  ...   62.71     64.78  16.23
1     002067.SZ 2015-12-25  374530.03  ...   24.40     24.50   9.30
2     002070.SZ 2015-12-25  698758.94  ...  114.30    114.44  24.92
3     600525.SH 2015-12-25  115307.14  ...  195.48    198.17  19.17
4     600535.SH 2015-12-25   60979.13  ...  315.03    323.05  41.50
        ...        ...        ...  ...     ...       ...    ...
7686  603617.SH 2020-06-09   17001.44  ...   21.37     21.45  10.73
7687  300656.SZ 2020-06-09   12851.04  ...   37.06     37.29  20.65
7688  603882.SH 2020-06-09   28640.03  ...   76.86     78.27  77.29
7689  002826.SZ 2020-06-09   29508.46  ...   11.03     11.26  10.99
7690  603136.SH 2020-06-09   27286.28  ...   35.26     37.66  23.60
```

windcode is the id of stocks and volume .. open are some features of the stock. I want to run a rolling-window regression on:

volume ~ 1 + adjlow + adjclose + open

(no sense but just for example)

For each panel contains all stocks and in 20 days, I run the regression. How can I realize it?
I know I can use loop, but I want some built-in functions.

I tried numpy_ext.rolling_apply(), but it need me to enter arrays one by one. Actually I have thousands of features needed to be used, so I don't know how to input these arguments by hand.

I want something like dataframe.groupby.apply(), which enables me to straightly operate the group.

Comment: Create a new column with what you need (e.g. `df['aggregate_per_line']=...` ), then apply the rolling there?